# deploy tf-serving issue with grpc deadline exceeded

Tags: tensorflow, tensorrt

help me with the tensorflow model deploy section. I;m getting issue related to deadline.

```
Exception in thread Thread-3:
stream1        | Traceback (most recent call last):
stream1        |   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
stream1        |     self.run()
stream1        |   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
stream1        |     self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
stream1        |   File "/app/camAppTF2.py", line 270, in frames
stream1        |     boxes, pred_conf = do_inference(image=image_data)
stream1        |   File "/app/tensorflow_client.py", line 36, in do_inference
stream1        |     result = stub.Predict(pred_request, 10) # 10 secs timeout
stream1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 826, in __call__
stream1        |     return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
stream1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 729, in _end_unary_response_blocking
stream1        |     raise _InactiveRpcError(state)
stream1        | grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
stream1        |        status = StatusCode.DEADLINE_EXCEEDED
stream1        |        details = "Deadline Exceeded"
stream1        |        debug_error_string = " {"created":"@1611235122.120446804","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:192.168.112.3:8500","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1056,"grpc_message":"Deadline Exceeded","grpc_status":4}"
```

This is the error occurred while running the tensorflow serving

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the tensorflow serving client is not able to make communication with server. Or this might also occur due to network error. If you are using a docker to host your tensorflow model server, you need to open the port in the container as mentioned below. You can also extend the time from default as in some cases model server closes before the request is reached. Thank you!

```
docker run --name=tensorflow_container -p 9020:9020 -it $USER/tensorflow-serving-devel
```